# Does $~\operatorname{adj(adj}(A)) = A~$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could someone help me prove whether this is true or false?

I somehow came to the conclusion that $~\operatorname{adj(adj}(A)) = A$, but I am not sure whether is true or not.

Comment: If you are visiting this website from a desktop computer, see the top question in the "Related" sidebar on the right.

Comment: I'd suggest trying this for $A=tI$ say.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A \in \mathrm M_n (\Bbb F)$. A well-known result is 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator\rank{rank}
\DeclareMathOperator\adj{adj}
\rank (\adj A) = \begin{cases}
n, & \rank A = n, \\
1, & \rank A = n-1, \\
0, & \rank A \leqslant n-2, 
\end{cases}
$$
where we assume that $n \geqslant 2$. Then for $n \geqslant 3$, 
$$
\rank (\adj (\adj A)) = \begin{cases}
n, & \rank A = n, \\
0, & \rank A < n,
\end{cases}
$$
while for $n = 2$, 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}, \adj A = \begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix},  \adj (\adj A) = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
When $\rank A = n$, i.e. $A$ is invertible, $\adj A$ is invertible as well. Since 
$$
A (\adj A) = (\det A) I, 
$$
we get $$\adj A = (\det A)A^{-1}, \det (\adj A) = (\det A)^{n-1}; (\adj A)^{-1} = A/(\det A).  $$ 
Replace $A$ by $\adj A$, 
$$
\adj (\adj A) = (\det (\adj A))(\adj A)^{-1} = (\det A)^{n-1} A/(\det A) = (\det A)^{n-2} A. 
$$
Thus when $n = 2, \adj (\adj A) = A$; for $n \geqslant 3$, 
$$
\adj (\adj A) = A \iff A = 0 \text{ or } \det A = 1 
$$

Comment: @user1551 Oh, thanks for pointing out this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of rows in a square matrix.
Now, Consider the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b\\0&0&c\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}; a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$$ Now, $$\hspace{35pt}adj(A)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&ac\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\\\implies adj(adj(A))=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\neq A$$

**Claim:** $adj(adj(A))=A$ holds if and only if $A=0$ or $|A|=1$ or $n=2$.

If $A=0$, then it's trivial.

For $n=2$, $$\text{Let}\ ,A=\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}$$ It is easy to see that $adj(adj(A))=A$

Now, We know that $adj(adj(A))=|A|^{n-2}A$ holds true for invertible matrices. It is because of the following: $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{|A|}\times adj(A)\\\implies adj(A)=|A|A^{-1}\\\implies adj(adj(A))=||A|A^{-1}|\times (|A|A^{-1})^{-1}\\\implies adj(adj(A))=|A|^{n-2}A$$
Therefore, $adj(adj(A))=A$ holds if and only if $|A|=1$.

Comment: What's up with your new edit? You've been assuming that $A$ is invertible. Why suddenly add an "$A=0$" clause in your conclusion? Are you now assuming that $A$ can be singular? If so, you need to take care of the corner cases $n=1$ and $n=2$. Note that $adj(adj(0))=1\ne0$ when $n=1$ and $adj(adj(A))=A$ for every $A$ (singular or not) when $n=2$.

Comment: Then you need to substantiate your conclusion, but due to your new edit, your conclusion is now wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $~A^{-1}=\frac{adj ~A}{det~A}~$

So $~adj~A=A^{-1}~det~A$

Multiply both the sides of equation by $(adj~A )^{−1}$, we get equation

$I=det~A~(adj~A )^{−1}~A^{-1}$

Multiplying both the sides by $~A~$, we get equation of the form:

$A=det~A~(adj~A )^{−1}~(A^{-1}~A)$

$\implies A=det~A~(adj~A )^{−1}$

$\implies \frac{A}{det~A}=(adj~A )^{−1}=\frac{adj ~(adj~A)}{det~(adj~A)}\quad$ ,by the definition of $(adj~A )^{−1}$

$\implies \frac{A}{det~A}=\frac{adj ~(adj~A)}{(det~A)^{n-1}}\quad$ , as $det~(adj~A)=(det~A)^{n-1}$

> $\implies adj ~(adj~A)=A~{(det~A)^{n-2}}$

---

Now if $~A~$ be a matrix such that $det~A=1~$, then $~adj ~(adj~A)=A$.

e.g., take the identity matrix $~I~$.